# compile="False" or compile="True"

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm doing a finetune for a pretrained model and saved it (model.h5). In finetune, I use  `load_model= ('model.h5', compile='False')`,So I would like to know when we make false and when we make "true" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.keras.models.load_model(
    filepath, custom_objects=None, compile = True, options=None
)
```

In this `compile="False" or compile="True"` is a boolean value, which will specify whether to compile the model after loading.

If the original model was compiled, and saved with the optimizer, then the returned model will be compiled after setting the `compile=True`. Otherwise((`if compile=False`), the model will be left uncompiled.

In the case that an uncompiled model is returned, a warning is displayed if the compile argument is set to `True`.